# Setting protected variable value in child class and accessing value in parent

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, protected

I'm not sure if this is even possible but here goes. I want to set the value of a protected variable from within a child class and then access that value from the parent class. This is what I have tried:

```
class A {
    protected $a;

    public function __construct() {
        new B;

        echo "Parent Value: {$this->a}";
    }

    protected function setter($value) {
        $this->a = $value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setter('set value');

        echo "Child Value: {$this->a}<br />";
    }
}


new A;
```

I'm expecting the output for the above code to be:

```
Child Value: set value
Parent Value: set value
```

However I get the following instead:

```
Child Value: set value
Parent Value:
```

Is it possible to set the value of a protected variable from within a child class and then access that value in the parent class? If not how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value and access it from the child class without any problems - you are actually doing that when you generate your `B`-class object in the `A`-class constructor - but the problem with your code is that you are generating a parent object and in the constructor of that parent object you generate a new object of the child class.

So what is happening is:

- You generate an `A` object, the constructor of the `A` class runs;
- In the constructor you generate a `B` object. **This is a new object**, unrelated to your current `A` object;
- The constructor of the `B` object you set the value and echo it (basically answering your own question), the first line of your output is as expected;
- Continuing in the constructor of the `A` object, you discard the generated `B`-class object and echo the value of `$this->a` but that value is not set for that object, so you get nothing.

I am kind of confused why you would want to construct a child object in the constructor of the parent. Normally I would construct a `B` object and in the constructor of that object, first call the parent constructor before doing `B`-specific stuff.

Comment: I'm just learning the concepts of OOP. Would it be possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do in another way?

Comment: @MeisamMulla What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Note that you already have accomplished setting and using the variable of the parent class from within the child class.

Comment: I want to set the value of `$a` in the child class and then access that same value from the parent. As for why, I'm just playing around with some concepts.

Comment: @MeisamMulla But you are already setting `$a` from the child class the moment you generate a `B`-class object. You are also accessing it from your `B`-class / child object when you `echo` the value. You are just missing the point that you are dealing with 2 different objects that have different values for the `$a` variable: The `A`-class object you generate at the end of the code and the `B`-class object you generate in the constructor of `A`.

Comment: @MeisamMulla Or perhaps you are looking for static properties: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I think I'm looking at this the wrong way.